# Weird encoding issues from Azure Blob causing unable to convert to object from JSON

Tags: json, azure

I restored my OSdisk in recovery vault in Azure to storage container, and got a blob and multiple JSON files. These JSON file are being generated by Azure during the restoration process.

I encountered problems when trying to convert the JSON file into PSobject using the following command

`$JsonContent =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $sourceSasUrl -ContentType 'application/json; charset=Unicode' | ConvertFrom-Json`

The error i have received is :

`ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (2): { ...`

The closest link that i have found is this, however, i tried to change to unicode and it doesn't work

[Weird characters from Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010577/weird-characters-when-reading-blob-from-container)

I noticed i can't even paste the characters here in the link, i can only show you using screenshot. 
[image: JSON file being generated]

Couple things that i have attempted:

1. Change to various encoding format in Charset.
2. Attempting to use regex to replace non-ASCII characters, however, i couldn't proceed further, because in JSON file, there are info such as `av20191220vm-osdisk-20191231-083906.vhd"` contains some special characters that i still need.

Comment: did you try to process it as unicode? because this doesnt show you doing that. you need to use something like `[system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString((irm xxx))`

Comment: @csamleong, Are you still having the issue ?

Comment: @4c74356b41 sorry for the late reply, i used `charset=Unicode'`, and I also replaced it with UTF-8, or UTF-16 to test the behaviour. 

I also tried to use the line below:
$json = (Get-Content 'D:\config-av20191220vm-2b29e4f2-299e-414c-a963-fa2415784ddd.json' -Encoding UTF8 |ConvertFrom-Json)

but the same error occurs. Do take note that if I manually removed the weird characters in my JSON file, these codes work fine.

Comment: @MonikaReddy-MSFT Same error occurs, seems like there is a problem with the file. If I manually removed those weird characters from my JSON, and rerun my PS script, it works fine. 

Currently, I used other methods to work around this issue, I am reading the storage blob directly and use `where-object` to get my VHD file.